# Does QueueTube download complete videos or audio only?

Tags: audio, youtube, video-streaming

There is a [Queuetube app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.StevenLustig.QueueTube) that enables listening to YouTube material while the application is minimized. YouTube app stops playing videos when minimized; this app plays sound only.

Does this mean it is downloading audio only or just playing audio from a downloaded video format?

This is important because I need to know how much memory my Xperia will download from YouTube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the developer. It was using the full video streams up until last week when I released version 1.8.

However it is possible that the android MediaPlayer when given a video stream, doesn't bother to download the video too, but I doubt so.

Now it specifically downloads audio-only streams, however only on Android 4.3+ devices.

Android 4.2 and lower still stream the full video because the OS isn't compatible with the audio only streams.

To give you an idea of bandwidth consumption, a 5 minute song takes up about...

- 3MB video stream, HD Audio disabled
- 12MB video stream, HD Audio enabled
- 3MB audio-only stream, if your device supports it. The sound quality is about equal (possibly a little better) than HD Audio with video.

On Android 4.3+ devices, the HD Audio switch in settings doesn't really do anything..

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments of reviewers, it's streaming only audio. So, it's lighter on the download.